# MVC Controller Not Binding Id Param On Post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, binding, jquery

I have a Model that has several properties. When I submit a form, I pass along the values for those properties (generated by the jQuery `$.serialize()` method) and they are automatically bound. This works without a problem. However, now I want to add an `Id` to the string, and I have to do it manually since it's not a form field. I've done so by appending `'&Id=' + myId` to the end of the URL being posted. The result is a fine query string (I've checked what's getting sent in Firebug and a valid ID is getting posted)

My Model has a property `Id`:

```
public Int32 Id { get; set; }
```

One would think that the Id would get bound automatically in the controller, but even though all the other data is, the Id is not. This is really frustrating. What could I possibly be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to this problem, and given the details I posted in the question, no one would have been able to answer it. I'm posting the answer because I feel like it could potentially help someone.

In my Model, my Id property has a few decorations that I left out because I didn't think they were important, but it turns out they are. Here's what my whole property looks like:

```
[DataMember(Name = "id")]        
[Column(Name = "id", AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert, IsDbGenerated = true, 
  IsPrimaryKey = true)]
public Int32 Id { get; set; }
```

Apparently, the `AutoSync` part of the decoration means that it syncs with the database and cannot actually be set declaratively. So if you're trying to do what I did, make sure you don't have `AutoSync` declared!

Hope this helps someone :)